# Carousel-caption links in Bootstrap carousel with fixed item position?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm implementing a fullscreen bootstrap carousel for a Wordpress homepage, where the slides are background-images set to background-size:cover. The images also need to fade from one to the next, and each slide contains an individual caption which is a separate link to another part of the site.

However, because I've had to set the .item class to 'position:fixed', the caption links are not working properly - although the text of each caption displays normally, only the final slide caption link is working, the others are "hidden" under it and so every caption links to the same URL, that of the last one.

Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel container slide carousel-fade">
 <div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="active item one">
   <div class="carousel-caption">
    <h2><a href="http://www.topographicwebdesign.co.uk/work-form/category/work/#astral">Astral Pattern</a></h2>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item two">
   <div class="carousel-caption">
    <h2><a href="http://www.topographicwebdesign.co.uk/work-form/category/work/#shark">Imaginary Music - La Shark</a></h2>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item three">
   <div class="carousel-caption">
    <h2><a href="http://www.topographicwebdesign.co.uk/work-form/category/work/#troubled">Troubled Waters</a></h2>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"></a><a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">    </a>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.carousel .item {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
    display:block;
    left:0px;
}
.carousel .one {
    background: url('http://www.topographicwebdesign.co.uk/work-form/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Bunhill-Walking-Map_small.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
}
.carousel .two {
    background: url('http://www.topographicwebdesign.co.uk/work-form/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Imaginary-Music_small.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
}
.carousel .three {
    background: url('http://www.topographicwebdesign.co.uk/work-form/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Sir-Johns-Nose_small.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
}
.carousel .active.left {
    left:0;
    opacity:0;
    z-index:2;
}
.carousel-control.left,.carousel-control.right{
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    border-radius:25px;
    -moz-border-radius:25px;
    -webkit-border-radius:25px;
    background-color:white;
    position:fixed;
    background-image:none;
}
.carousel-caption{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:10px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    text-shadow:none;
}
.carousel-control {
    cursor:pointer;
}
.carousel-control.left {
    left:10px;
    right:auto;
    top:50%;
} 
.carousel-control.right {
    right:10px;
    top:50%;
}
a.carousel-control:hover{
    background-color:white;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .item {
  opacity: 0;
  transition-property: opacity;
  transition-duration: .8s;
  -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
  -webkit-transition-duration: .8s;
  -moz-transition-property: opacity;
  -moz-transition-duration: .8s;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active {
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.right {
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .next.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .prev.right {
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-control {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

And here is the Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.carousel').carousel({interval: 5000});
  });
</script>
```